# How can I use a function declared before a class, inside that class in in python 3?

Tags: python, function, class

I have this really simple scenario where I want to use one function in multiple classes. So I declare it before the class and then I try to use.

```py
def __ext_function(x):
    print(f'Test{x}')
    
class MyClass():
    some_value: int

    def __init__(self, some_value):
        self.some_value = some_value
        __ext_function(1)

a = MyClass(some_value=1)
```

But for some reason it keeps telling me that it does not exit:

> NameError: name '_MyClass__ext_function' is not defined

I have seen other questions with solutions like this:

```py
def __ext_function(x):
    print(f'Test {x}')
    
class MyClass():
    some_value: int
    ext_func = staticmethod(__ext_function)
    def __init__(self, some_value):
        self.some_value = some_value
        self.ext_func(1)

a = MyClass(some_value=1)
```

But none seems to work.

Comment: Don't begin the function name with double underscore. That has special meaning inside classes.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name. This is normally used for "private" _methods_, but IMHO, it's quite strange that the name gets mangled even for global functions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case where Python's usually pure syntax fails.  Symbols that start with two underscores get treated specially in a class.  If you change that function name to `_ext_function`, it will work exactly as you expect.